# C code doesn't show in the output zero number

Tags: c++, formatting

When I'm compiling the following source code, in the output the zero doesn't correctly show. Why? I want the output text to have the following format:

```
01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08
```

not 1 2 3 4....

How can I fix this issue?

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[3][4] = {  
    {00, 01, 02, 03} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
    {04, 05, 06, 07} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
    {08, 09, 10, 11}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < 4; ++t)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][t] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%02d\b", a[i][t]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [printf manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Look for the padding with 0:

> 0
>
> The value should be zero padded. For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f,
>   F, g, and G conversions, the converted value is padded on the left
>   with zeros rather than blanks. If the 0 and - flags both appear, the 0
>   flag is ignored. If a precision is given with a numeric conversion (d,
>   i, o, u, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored. For other conversions, the
>   behavior is undefined.

and look for the field width:

> The field width
>
> An optional decimal digit string (with nonzero first digit) specifying
>   a minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters
>   than the field width, it will be padded with spaces on the left (or
>   right, if the left-adjustment flag has been given). Instead of a
>   decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal
>   integer m) to specify that the field width is given in the next
>   argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type
>   int. A negative field width is taken as a '-' flag followed by a
>   positive field width. In no case does a nonexistent or small field
>   width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is
>   wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the
>   conversion result.

solution use:

```
printf("%02d\b", a[i][t]);
```

and drop the 0 from literal (01, 02...) or they will be taken as octal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

0 before number tells compiler, that this number is in octal notation. You cannot do this with numbers, only with chars, or with right format in printf. Actually your code is incorrect and should never compiles, since there is no digits `8` and `9` in octal.